# On the intersection of integral closure of powers of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions, primary-decomposition

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $J$ be a proper ideal of $R$ . Let $Min(R)$ be the set of minimal primes of $R$ (this set is finite as $R$ is Noetherian).

Then how to prove that $\cap_{n\ge 1}\overline{J^n}=\cap_{P\in Min(R), J+P\ne R}P$ ?

Here, for an ideal $I$, $\overline{I}$ denotes the [integral closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_closure_of_an_ideal) of the ideal $I$.

I know the following facts which I think will be useful here, but I'm not sure how to use it ... here goes: Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$. Then the following holds:

(1) Let $a\in R$. Then $a\in \overline I$ iff for every minimal prime $P$ of $R$, the image of $a$ in $R/P$ lies in $\overline {I+P/P}$ .

(2) Let $P\in Ass(R/\overline I)$ . Then there is a minimal prime ideal $Q\subseteq P$ such that $P/Q\in Ass (R/\overline{I+Q})$ .

Please help.

Comment: May I ask why the statement is true?

Comment: @Youngsu: which statement are you referring to ? The question is Exercise 5.15 in Swanson, Huneke book, Integral Closure of Rings, Modules and Ideals. The fact (1) I state is Proposition 1.1.5 of the same book, the fact (2) I state is Lemma 5.4.4. part (1) of the same book ...

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think it will make your question more interesting and valuable if you could add the source of your question. At least you can say they are in the book of Swanson and Huneke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (*) If $I+Q = R$ and $I + Q' = R$, then $I + Q\cap Q' = R$.

Proof: $R = (I+Q)(I+Q') = I^2 +IQ + IQ' + QQ' \subset I + QQ' \subset I + Q \cap Q'$.

Let $\{ P_1,\dots,P_n, Q_1,\dots, Q_s \}$ be the set of minimal primes of $R$ such that $I + P_i \neq R$ and $I + Q_j = R$. 
Write $P' = \cap P_i$ and $Q' = \cap Q_j$. 
Since $\overline{I^n} + Q' = R$ by (*), there exists $x \in \overline{I^n}$ and $q \in Q'$ such that $x + q = 1$. 
For any $p \in P'$, one has
$$
px + pq = p. 
$$
Notice that $px \in \overline{I^n}$ and $pq \subset P' \cap Q' = \sqrt{0} \subset \overline{I^n}$ (as $\sqrt{0}$ is the set of nilpotent elements of $R$). 
Thus, $p \in \overline{I^n}$. This shows that $P' \subset \cap \overline{I^n}$.

Now, we show that $J:= \cap \overline{I^n} \subset P$ for $P \in \{ P_1,\dots,P_n\}$. 
Since $I+ P \neq R$, $I(R/P)$ is a proper ideal of $(R/P)$.
Then there exists a DVR $(A,N)$ containing $R/P$ such that $I \subset N \cap R/P$ (cf. Theorem 6.4.3 in [SH]).
Furthermore, for all $n \ge 1$,
$$
J(R/P) \subset \overline{I^n} (R/P) \subset \overline{I^n}A \subset \overline{N^n} = N^n.
$$
The last equality follows since $N$ is principal and $A$ normal (I believe this is in Ch 1 in [SH]).
Since $J(R/P) \subset \cap N^n = (0)$ by Krull's intersection theorem, $J(R/P) = (0)$. Thus, $J \subset P$.